# Can the command of a Command spell be clarified with gestures?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

The Command spell states:

> You speak a one-word command to a creature you can see within range. The target must succeed on a Wisdom saving throw or follow the command on its next turn.

If there were two doors and you pointed at one and gave the Command, "exit" - are there any guidelines as to whether the gesture part of the Command clarifies the command or does the creature get to choose how to interpret the command?

Answer (score 30):

### While gestures aren't part of the spell's magic, they might still be interpreted.

Before I start, the spell does explicitly say that the DM determines how the target behaves, so it's ultimately the DM's call. As I read it, gestures are not part of the magic of the spell, but they might be part of the mundane context of the command.

First, [spells only do exactly what they say they do](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/107637/what-is-the-source-of-the-spells-do-only-what-they-say-they-do-rules-interpret), and no more. If gestures were part of the magical command, they would have been included in the text of the spell. Specifically, the one-word limit reduces the spell's versatility--adding gestures basically bypasses that limitation.

Second, the spell only requires that you can see the target, not that the target can see you. If you try to use gestures to Command a creature that can't see you, does it still work? Nothing in the spell text says that the creature can somehow understand a gesture it can't see, because gestures are not part of the spell.

However, creatures have to use mundane, nonmagical context to interpret the command that they're given. For example, "approach" means that the creature has to locate you and figure out how they're going to move closer to you, and "drop" means the creature has to identify whatever they're holding and drop it.

If you issue the command "exit," and point, the creature may use the information you give it in order to carry out its command. However, they are not magically compelled to do anything other than strictly follow the single word command, so they might exit via other means, like teleporting away.

Comment: I like this answer because it uses good logic around how the command is interpreted, rather than just how it is issued.

Comment: And here I thought 'drop' was telling them to go prone.

Comment: Can a creature execute command which might be considered involuntary action ? For example "sleep!"

Comment: @Gnudiff: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/117612/effects-of-command-spell-sleep

Comment: Why are you subtly putting stuff into the spell effect [p.4] right after stating that it cannot be [p.2]. Make up your mind, please. The creature have to execute the command, but on its own [DM / Player] convenience. The Q hints at an attempt of using "Command" as it would "Suggestion". There is no context conveyance. -1

Comment: @Mindwin The distinction that I'm drawing is between the magical compulsion and the mundane surrounding context that the creature uses to carry out the command. I've edited the question to hopefully make it more clear.

Comment: Does anyone know how this rule is implemented in translations?-- in some languages, such as Turkish, the whole notion of a "word" doesn't really work: In Turkish, one "word" could be used to translate "exit through the door on my left".

Comment: @icyfire Sorry for attempting to lecture senpai, but the stack is to build up an expert knowledge base. You lost objectivity with the ambiguity. I reverted my vote. But I will show my face to the peer judgement and post my 2p in a voteable (up or down) answer.

Comment: @Mindwin I'm fine with the lecturing :) However I still don't quite understand your argument--can you explain a bit more how I lost objectivity?

Comment: @icyfire see v2 https://rpg.stackexchange.com/revisions/120852/2 - what you added in the "However ..." paragraph solved the ambiguity. When giving advice here, we have to be wary of how the rules lawyer might twist our *"expert advice"* to their advantage.

Answer (score 14):

The DM chooses how to interpret the command should you use any command other than the ones written within the spells description.

> You might issue a command other than one described here. If you do so, the DM determines how the target behaves.

Comment: It clearly says "you speak a one word command" Issuing other commands does not equate to "issuing a command a different way".

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say. The description of spell clearly states that there are several commands that have descriptions of their own such as Approach,Drop and exit is not one of those commands and according to the description of the spell if the effect of the command is not described then the DM decides what happens.

Answer (score 1):

**No**

The command spell **cannot be clarified** with any cues. It gives a single word command, that will be carried out in the next turn, if possible. If you need more nuance, then the right spell is **Suggestion**. That both allows  clarification and has a longer duration.

The *"exit"* command, you suggested would make the creature to move towards the nearest exit. In a situation with two doors, it would exit the room through the nearest door, assuming the door was reacheable in a single turn.

Comment: Why nearest exit? Why not safest or most useful or most reasonable? What’s the source of the logic for making the decision?

Comment: @praxiteles: the creature will attempt to execute the command to the best of its ability. If the command is "EXIT" of course it will go to the nearest. Picture yourself **in panic inside a building on fire.** where will you go? The nearest exit?

Comment: Hmm...If at dinner, a PC dining receives the Command to "Exit", and one nearby door leads upstairs to a guarded area where the PC might be attacked, and one farther door leads outside to safety - would the PC still take the nearest door because they "panic"? Would they be unable to take the safest door ? Where is panic clarified as a mindset part of the spell and the choice on how to execute the Command removed?

Comment: Remember that the DM (or player, if targeting their character) would decide how the target reacts to the command. There is no explicit rule that would make a creature go through the nearest exit, or even make it run or Dash to do so, if given the command "exit." A creature that failed the save will simply be "exiting" for the duration of their next turn. How that looks is up to the reasonable interpretation of the person controlling the affected character.
Notably, although not explicit in the spell, it seems targets won't perform other actions during their turn (see the spell's examples).